# Hadoop services are running. But it says fails to connect

Tags: java, hadoop

```
  package org.myorg;

  import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;

  import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;

  public class Write{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
           try {
                // UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("hbase");

                 UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser();

                 ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {
                     public Void run() throws Exception
                     {
                         Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                         conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://10.72.40.XX:8020/user/hbase");

                        //conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hbase");

                         conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "root");
                         FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

                         fs.createNewFile(new Path("/user/hbase/test"));

                         System.out.println("File Created");
                        return null;
                     }
                 });
               }
          catch(Exception e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

 }
}
```

This is my java file.

My ip is 10.72.40.XX

```
  hostname -i
```

gives this ip to me.

```
 jps
```

says

```
 Jobtracker, namenode, datanode, tasktracker, secondarynamenode, jps
```

are running.

I compiled this java program using

```
 javac -classpath hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar -d Write/ Write.java
```

Created jar using

```
 jar -cvf Write.jar -C Write/ .
```

Run this program using

```
 hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop jar Write.jar org.myorg.Write
```

It says,

```
 Retrying 0-9 [10] times

  failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Then i checked if something is listening at port 8020

```
 netstat -plten | grep java

 tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8020       :::*                        LISTEN      0          55639      15717/java
```

returns service is listening at port 8020.

Then, for debugging purpose, i replaced ip with localhost, It is succeeded. What could be the problem?

How do i solve it?

Does ip and localhost are different for the same machine?

Comment: plus1 for the security mindedness of hiding the last octet of your local ip address!

Comment: What is the actual output of the netstat command?

Comment: @muru updated the question with netstat actual outpu

Comment: @GopsAB There you have it. The process is only listening on localhost, that's why you can only connect on localhost. Look through the configuration, there must be some place where you can specify which IP/interface it should listen on.

Comment: ok muru. So i should change localhost to my ip in my conf file. Right?

Comment: @muru Credit goes to you. I thought  both loclahost and ip are same. But you cracked it. Please add it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `netstat` output indicates that it is only listening on localhost (`::ffff:127.0.0.1:8020` is port 8020 on localhost). You could edit your service configuration, where there must be an entry for the interface/IP it listens on. There, you can change `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` to the external IP. For many services, you can use `0.0.0.0` to indicate that it should listen on all services.

Comment: Thanks. edit `core-site.xml` where there is a value `localhost:8020`. Replace it with the ip. Then it ll work fine.

Comment: Will you please help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582312/connection-is-not-being-established)