# Connection is not being established

Tags: hadoop, docker, telnet, flume, netstat

I have two running container for flume and hadoop. Let it be hadoop2 and flume2. I created these two containers from two images namely hadoop_alone and flume_alone.

```
   docker run -d -p 10.236.173.XX:8020:8020 -p 10.236.173.XX:50030:50030 -p 10.236.173.XX:50060:50060 -p 10.236.173.XX:50070:50070 -p 10.236.173.XX:50075:50075 -p 10.236.173.XX:50090:50090 -p 10.236.173.XX:50105:50105 --name hadoopservices hadoop_alone
```

I get into hadoop container and checked for exposed ports. So All the ports are exposed properly.

```
    docker run -d --name flumeservices -p 0.0.0.0:5140:5140 -p 0.0.0.0:44444:44444 --link hadoopservices:hadoopservices flume_alone
```

I get into flume container and checked for `env` and `etc/hosts` entries. There is an entry for hadoopservices and `env` variables are created automatically.

My `core-site.xml`

```
 fs.defaultFS
 hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020
```

I modified it so it ll accept services at 8020 from all the containers.

My source and sink in flume.conf

```
 a2.sources.r1.type = netcat
 a2.sources.r1.bind = localhost
 a2.sources.r1.port = 5140

 a2.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
 a2.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
 a2.sinks.k1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
 a2.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://hadoopservices:8020/user/root/syslog/%y-%m-%d/%H%M/%S
 a2.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = events
 a2.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute
 a2.sinks.k1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
```

I restarted hadoop namenode after changing `core-site.xml`.

I try to write into hdfs from flume using

```
/usr/bin/flume-ng agent --conf-file /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf --name a2 -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

It says

```
INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream
```

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

So i found something is the problem with connection established between these two contianers. I get into hadoop container and checked for port connections

```
netstat -tna


tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52521         127.0.0.1:8020          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8020          127.0.0.1:52516         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52516         127.0.0.1:8020          ESTABLISHED
```

But i expect it to be

```
tcp        0      0 172.17.1.XX:54342       172.17.1.XX:8020        TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 172.17.1.XX:54332       172.17.1.XX:8020        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.17.1.XX:8020        172.17.1.XX:54332       ESTABLISHED
```

Where 172.17.1.XX is the ip of my hadoop container.

I found the cause. Is it the reason?

Which configuration should be modified? And or my run statement? What should be changed to establish connection between these two docker containers so that i can able to write into hdfs from flume.

If you need more info, i 'll edit it further.

Please tell me some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody face the same problem, please do the following steps.

```
 1) Check whether 0.0.0.0:8020 is updated in core-site.xml

 2) If you update it inside running container, **I suggest you all to restart ALL the services NOT ONLY namenode**. [better do as part of Dockerfile]

 3) Check for `env` and `etc/hosts` contents in flume container 

 4) And hostname in `etc/hosts` must be matched with the `hdfs path` parameter in flume.conf

 5) Get into hadoop container and do `netstat -tna` and you must see connection established to <hadoop_container_ip>:8020. Not to your localhost[127.0.0.1].
```

I hope it 'll be helpful to the people who tries to link containers and port mapping.